# How to let users install pre-built apps like wordpress plugin on a nodejs / vuejs / postgres SaaS webapp

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vue.js, vuejs3, saas

I would like to create a SaaS app where user start with a very simple webapp to which they could add functionnalities once they are available.
The constraint is I don't want to impose those functionalities and I want the user to be able to install them only if they want to.

This is how work wordpress with plugins. But how to do this kind of thing with a vuejs project that is built ? Once it's built there is no way to bring in new stuff right ?

This would ne paired with a REST api + Postgres.

As anyone created or used something that let us build those kind of webapp ?
I need help to know in which direction I should search about this.

Thanks !!

Comment: Main app and plugins can be built separately. You can load plugin bundles with SystemJS or another transport and use as dynamic components or nested apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ill search in that way.